# The CSS Code does not Display in HTML Server

Tags: html, css

Hello **Stack Overflow Community**,

I would like to ask for help regarding my concern on CSS not showing in my HTML Display. I am still new to the Programming World. Please bear with me. I am doing a tutorial course in HTML YouTube by PinoyFreeCoder.

Here is the **HTML** that I made:

```
    <title>PinoyFreeCoder Blog</title>
    <style type="text/css"> 
        body{background-color: #F5F5F5; margin-left: 20%; margin-right: 20%; border: 2px dotted black; padding:10px 10px 10px 10px; 
          font-family: sans-serif;}
   </style>
  <link rel="icon" href="Images/John Canero Logo.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">**
 </head>

 <body>
 <header id="main header">
      <h1>PinoyFreeCoder.com</h1>
 </header>
```

Here is the **Style.css** that I made:

```
  *{
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }

  #main-header{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the actual problem? What isn't happening that should? What is happening that shouldn't? Your styles.css references an element with ID main-header. yet we have no example of that in your HTML. It's time to learn about Developer Tools in your browser. The Network tab will show you if the css file is loaded (if not you can check the path) and the "inspect" tool will enable you to view what styles are applied to an element and if any styles are being overridden.

Comment: I updated the post. Thank you for the help and my pardon.

Comment: You  [can't have a space in the id attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) . Spaces have special meaning in some attributes an CSS selector, only use them when you know what their purpose is  You should use `<header id="mainHeader">` and `#mainHeader`

Comment: I got and solved it! 

Thank you Jon P for the help! This is my first time to question in stack overflow. I appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here if you are applying styling in `HTML` page itself. Then, whatever `CSS` you want to give to your webpage you can mention it betweeen `<style></style>` tag.

```html
<title>PinoyFreeCoder Blog</title>
    <style> 
        body{background-color: red; margin-left: 20%; margin-right: 20%; border: 2px dotted black; padding:10px 10px 10px 10px; 
          font-family: sans-serif;}
   </style>
  <body>
  <header id="main header">
      <h1>PinoyFreeCoder.com</h1>
 </header>
  </body>
```

And if you are using external `CSS` then you have to attach the  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` between your `<head></head>` tag. Then only all the `CSS` written in your external stylesheet will be applied.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<h2>I am formatted with a linked style sheet.</h2>

<p>Me too!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**styles.css**

```
body{
 background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: @John Cañero If this answer solves your issue then please mark it as correct ans. Else let me know if you're still facing any problems.

Comment: I tried on the both sides earlier and it only worked on the 1st solution. Yet Jon P answered my question awhile ago, he stated that you can't have a space in the id attribute.

Thank you also Uttam for the help. I appreciate it.